# Django Find difference in the same model instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I've been searching around and I don't think I've found my answer quite yet. But I'm looking to be able to find differences in data and have a list of column names that show that.

Take for instance I have a model just called my_model that has some columns.

```py
object = my_model.objects.get(id=1)

# Perform edit some values.

old_object = my_model.objects.get(id=1)

object.save()

# Check for differences
model_fields = [field.name for field in my_model._meta.get_fields()]

filtered_list = filter(lambda field: getattr(object, field, None) != getattr(old_object, field, None), model_fields)
```

Purpose of this is to notify the user after they make an update on their end to send an email to that user to just give them a reminder that they changed whatever values they changed.

Comment: Library [`django-simple-history`](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) might be useful to you.

Comment: @RossRogers I did see this, my thing is how big of an overhead does this add to processing time?

Comment: `django-simple-history` adds a parallel table with all of the same fields, plus some history fields like `history_time`, `history_edit`, `history_user`, `history_change_reason`.  When you are looking at differences, you query that audit table, completely separately from your normal table.  You access it like `Foo.history.filter(id=42, history_time_gte='2021-12-06-19:30')` et c.    Anyways, separate data, so more than double data size.  Depends on your requirements, but I found it very easy.  Want an audit table? `history = HistoricalRecords()` on that model and bam!  Done.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to answer my own question. Converting the two objects to dictionaries. I was able to end up with something like

```py
dict1, dict2 = obj1.__dict__, obj2._dict__

changed_fields = {
    'column_names': []
}

excluded_keys = '_state'

for k,v in dict1.items():
    if k in excluded_keys:
        continue
    try:
        if v != dict2[k]
        changed_fields['column_names'].append(k)
    except KeyError:
    # Put error handling
        continue
```